# count of values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the count of values when the value gets changed to 0 for the current record.

im not much familier with sql , tried self join but dint worked

see Input records below.

```
Date, value
2018-12, 0
2018-11, 1
2018-10, 1
2018-09, 1
2018-08, 0
2018-07, 0
2018-06, 1
2018-05, 0
2018-04, 1
2018-03, 0
2018-02, 0
2018-01, 1
```

output shroud be as below .

```
Date, value, Count
2018-12, 0 , 3
2018-11, 1 , 2
2018-10, 1 , 1
2018-09, 1 , 0
2018-08, 0 , 0
2018-07, 0 , 2
2018-06, 1 , 1
2018-05, 1 , 0
2018-04, 0 , 0
2018-03, 0 , 0
2018-02, 0 , 1
2018-01, 1 ,null
```

for the first record 2018-12, 0 we need to track when first occurrence of 0 came.once 0 came we need to stop count there.

In this case 0 came on 2018-08, 0 for the first record 2018-12, 0 . so we need to keep count 3 for 2018-12, 0.

For 2018-11, 1 we got 0 after two values so we need to keep 2.

For 2018-08, 0 we got 0 immediately so 0 need to keep.

For 2018-07, 0 we got 0 after two values so 2 need to keep like that.

Im not good at writing sql, please help how to write sql for this scenario.

Comment: you can try to use `sum` window function and `lead` window function

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I will check this tomorrow. If you get a chance could you provide the working query for this please

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a grouping.  The grouping appears to be the number of 0s on or later than every row.  You can calculate this using a cumulative sum.

Then, within each grouping, you can use `row_number()` for the calculation:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by grp order by "Date" asc) - 1) as counter
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by "Date" desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
order by "Date" desc;
```

I'm not sure why the earliest value would be `NULL`, so I didn't include that in the logic.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c3693d22de1081448e601c94022f4c66) is a db<>fiddle (note this uses Postgres but the important code is the same).

Comment: This code worked like a champ!... thank you so much for this..  please ignore that Null value.